# Excel - instant conversion from text data value to real data value

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

I have a set of dates stored as the text value (cells formatted as "General"), which are i.e. 12.11, 10.11, 30.05, 1.06 etc.

Now I want to produce the chart with these values, but it constantly throws the numbers (with the order from the beginning instead).

[image]

According the following threads:
[Is it possible to convert a text date to one stored as a date in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/889696/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-text-date-to-one-stored-as-a-date-in-excel)
and
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252

I tied to play with the `DATEVALUE` function by typing like this:

```
=DATEVALUE(B4)
```

but as you can see above I keep getting #VALUE instead.

Is there any way of turning these numbers on the left to the proper dates in Excel with keeping exactly the same days they show? I don't need a year, I need just the DD/MM format from Jan 1 to Dec 31. Is it possible?

Comment: `=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),RIGHT(A1,2),LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3))`

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks!